# Accepting formatted Json (multi-line) input from user in a Java console app with Scanner (all lines not being read)

Tags: java, json, java-8, java.util.scanner, stringbuilder

I have a scenario where I need to take formatted Json (multi-line) as an input and do something with it. I figured doing it in a simple console app would be good since it is just a tool I am creating and want it to be able to be ran locally. If I should be reading the Json from a file instead please let me know.

The plan is to have the user paste something like this into a console application and then type "exit".

```
    {
       "section1":{
          "line1":0.3456,
          "line2":{
             "line3":45345,
             "line4":67567
          },
          "section2":{
             "line6":867867,
             "line7":0.16767
          },
          "section3":{
             "line9":9977,
             "line10":0.76867
          },
          "array1":[
             {
                "ghjf":"1111",
                "ggeeaaa":678769,
                "ghj":0.6799789
             }
          ]
       }
    }
exit
```

A couple of things are happening:
1. The first { is not being recognized so I need to manually insert it.
2. Several lines are not being read... i.e. "line1" is getting skipped and many more.

**Here is my code:**

```
System.out.println("Enter a valid JSON string: ");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (!scanner.nextLine().equals("exit")) {
    sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
}

sb.insert(0, "{");

String formattedJson = sb.toString()
        .replaceAll("\\t","").replaceAll("\\s", "");


 // Do something with formattedJson further in code...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling scanner.nextLine() twice, but only use the value once.

Try declaring it as a variable and only calling nextLine() once:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("exit")) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

As a result, you probably won't need (should remove) this:

```
sb.insert(0, "{");
```

Comment: Ughh can't believe I didn't realize this. Thank you so much. Just out of curiosity are there any other techniques other then making the user type something like "exit" for the program to proceed? The ideal scenario would be to make it so the user pastes in the string and hits enter. So maybe I should check for an empty string instead.

Comment: Well you could consider a blank line as an acceptable terminator. Otherwise you could count the left braces as they appear and wait for the corresponding right brace to appear. As you get left braces increment, as you get right braces, decrement. When you get to zero, you're done.